# overwriting PUT requests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, webdav, rights

I'm using a library (rightjs) to make xhr requests to a server which only accepts PUT requests for a certain api call. Looking at the code, the library seems to overwrite the method to be POST and appends the method in a querystring parameter:

```
if (method == 'put' || method == 'delete') {
  add_params._method = method;
  method = 'post';
}
```

(the query string is formed calling .map() on add_params later on)

I'm not familiar with the reason for this, but I'm guessing it intends to support servers which do not have WebDAV functionality. I'd like to contribute to the library but don't want to outright delete this code since it seems like there must be a good reason for it.

Why does this library do this, and what methods can I use to figure out if its needed?

Answer (score 0):

(a) This has nothing to do with WebDAV. (b) There used to be libs and intermediaries not supporting PUT, and this was a workaround (which of course requires the server to support it).

Comment: How can I test for server support, ideally without making redundant submissions?